# Why I cannot apply a function to a list of lm fit using map?

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr, lm

I am fitting linear regression model to different groups using nested data frame and `map` function. After that, I want to conduct segmented regression to each fit of `lm`.

In this example, `diamonds2` contains a column `Fit_lm` with `lm` fit of each group. After that, I thought I can use `map` again to apply the `segmented` function, but the code did not work (see `diamonds3`).

Nevertheless, if I combined `lm` and `segmented` in the same function, the code worked (see `diamonds4`).

If possible, I would like to learn the reason why `map` and `segmented` cannot work on the `lm` object? Does this has something to do with how the `map` function work? Of course, I can do the same thing like `diamonds4`, but since I have already fit `lm` once, this strategy is not efficient.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(segmented)

data("diamonds")

diamonds2 <- diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(Fit_lm = map(data, ~lm(price ~ carat, data = .x))) 

diamonds3 <- diamonds2 %>%
  # segmented regression
  mutate(Fit_seg = map(Fit_lm, ~segmented(.x, seg.Z = ~carat)))
# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Fit_seg`.
# x cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
# i Input `Fit_seg` is `map(Fit_lm, ~segmented(.x, seg.Z = ~carat))`.
# i The error occured in group 1: cut = "Fair".
# Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

diamonds4 <- diamonds2 %>%
  #  lm and segmented regression
  mutate(Fit_seg = map(data, function(x){
    fit <- lm(price ~ carat, data = x)
    fit2 <- segmented(fit, seg.Z = ~carat)
    return(fit2)
  }))
```

Comment: It's not a `map` thing; the same thing happens with `lapply`. Running it through the debugger, it looks like it's a product of how environments are handled in `segmented.lm`; the line `mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())` is what's erroring out.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for checking on this. I think you are right. This is related how environments are handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need data in the function when you run `segmented`. Also data should have the same name as it was when you ran `lm`.

So this works :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(segmented)

diamonds2 %>%
  mutate(Fit_seg = map2(data, Fit_lm, ~segmented(.y, seg.Z = ~carat)))

#  cut       data                  Fit_lm Fit_seg   
#  <ord>     <list>                <list> <list>    
#1 Ideal     <tibble [21,551 × 9]> <lm>   <segmentd>
#2 Premium   <tibble [13,791 × 9]> <lm>   <segmentd>
#3 Good      <tibble [4,906 × 9]>  <lm>   <segmentd>
#4 Very Good <tibble [12,082 × 9]> <lm>   <segmentd>
#5 Fair      <tibble [1,610 × 9]>  <lm>   <segmentd>
```

but this will not :

```
diamonds2 %>%
  mutate(Fit_seg = map2(Fit_lm, data, ~segmented(.x, seg.Z = ~carat)))
```

This is because your data was named `.x` when you ran `lm`.

So it will fail even if you run with an anonymous function because `.x` is different from `x`.

```
diamonds2 %>% mutate(Fit_seg = map2(data, Fit_lm, 
            function(x, y) segmented(y, seg.Z = ~carat)))
```

So I guess the best solution is to use `segmented` along with `lm` in the same function so you have both data and `lm` object together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In your first code example, why we don't have to specify `.x` in the `map2` function?  I checked the documentation of the `segmented` function, and there is not an argument to specify the `data`, so I am curious.

Comment: `segmented` does not have `data` argument. The data should be present in the environment in which it is called and with the same name. I haven't used `segmented` either but I got a hint when I ran `segmented(diamonds2$Fit_lm[[1]], seg.Z = ~carat)` which returns `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.x' not found`

Comment: So it is OK that `map2` can have `.x` missing? Your first code example only has `.y`. Does that make the `segmented` function to look for `data` in the environment?

Comment: `.x` is not missing.We chose not to use it anywhere in the function we are calling.  `segmented` function looks for data in the environment by default. The purpose of `.x` is to only be available in the environment where `segmented` is being called.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with the new dplyr 1.0.0

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(segmented)

data("diamonds")

diamonds2 <- diamonds %>%
  nest_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(fit_lm = list(lm(price ~ carat,data = data)),
         seg = list(segmented(fit_lm,seg.Z = ~carat)))

diamonds2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 4
#> # Rowwise:  cut
#>   cut                     data fit_lm seg       
#>   <ord>     <list<tbl_df[,9]>> <list> <list>    
#> 1 Fair             [1,610 x 9] <lm>   <segmentd>
#> 2 Good             [4,906 x 9] <lm>   <segmentd>
#> 3 Very Good       [12,082 x 9] <lm>   <segmentd>
#> 4 Premium         [13,791 x 9] <lm>   <segmentd>
#> 5 Ideal           [21,551 x 9] <lm>   <segmentd>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  ctype    English_United Kingdom.1252 
#>  tz       America/Sao_Paulo           
#>  date     2020-06-05                  
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version    date       lib source                              
#>  assertthat    0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  backports     1.1.7      2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  blob          1.2.1      2020-01-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  broom         0.5.6      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  callr         3.4.3      2020-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  cellranger    1.1.0      2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  cli           2.0.2      2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  colorspace    1.4-1      2019-03-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  crayon        1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  DBI           1.1.0      2019-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  dbplyr        1.4.4      2020-05-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  desc          1.2.0      2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  devtools      2.3.0      2020-04-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  digest        0.6.25     2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1      2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  evaluate      0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  fansi         0.4.1      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  forcats     * 0.5.0      2020-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  fs            1.4.1      2020-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  generics      0.0.2      2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.1      2020-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  glue          1.4.1      2020-05-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  gtable        0.3.0      2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  haven         2.3.0      2020-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  highr         0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  hms           0.5.3      2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  htmltools     0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  httr          1.4.1      2019-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  jsonlite      1.6.1      2020-02-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  knitr         1.28       2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  lattice       0.20-41    2020-04-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  lifecycle     0.2.0      2020-03-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  lubridate     1.7.8      2020-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  magrittr      1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  memoise       1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  modelr        0.1.8      2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  munsell       0.5.0      2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  nlme          3.1-147    2020-04-13 [2] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  pillar        1.4.4      2020-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  pkgbuild      1.0.8      2020-05-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  pkgload       1.1.0      2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1      2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  processx      3.4.2      2020-02-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  ps            1.3.3      2020-05-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4      2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  R6            2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  Rcpp          1.0.4.6    2020-04-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  readr       * 1.3.1      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  readxl        1.3.1      2019-03-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  remotes       2.1.1      2020-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  reprex        0.3.0      2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  rlang         0.4.6      2020-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  rmarkdown     2.2        2020-05-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  rvest         0.3.5      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  scales        1.1.1      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  segmented   * 1.1-0      2019-12-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  stringi       1.4.6      2020-02-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  testthat      2.3.2      2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  tibble      * 3.0.1      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  tidyr       * 1.1.0      2020-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  tidyselect    1.1.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.0.9000 2020-05-16 [1] Github (tidyverse/tidyverse@1d7f9b7)
#>  usethis       1.6.1      2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  utf8          1.1.4      2018-05-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  vctrs         0.3.0      2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  withr         2.2.0      2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  xfun          0.14       2020-05-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  xml2          1.3.2      2020-04-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#>  yaml          2.2.1      2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)                      
#> 
#> [1] C:/Users/brunotc1/Documents/R/win-library/4.0
#> [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/library
```

Comment: It works fine for me but I think the answer should start with `diamonds2`. OP has already figured out that it works if done together.

Comment: Yes I did not answer on why segmented fails, I had never used the package, my best guess is that the scope is missing out the carat variable, op solution requires two steps in order to preserve the lm result, or some unnesting of the answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is my first time to see how `nest_by` works.

Comment: No problem dplyr 1.0.0 is really new on CRAN, I see that most map problems can be solved using it